# Meaning of "SCA" in flag SCA_MIGRATE_ENABLE/DISABLE in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, preempt-rt

These flags are defined in `kernel/sched/sched.h` and are used when enabling/disabling migration for a task in `core.c`. I haven't been able to determine what **SCA** is short for from looking at the code or patch notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent two hours trying to dig it up from kernel's Git history and it seems the first apparition of this prefix starts from commit **[9cfc3e18adb0362533e911bf3ce6ec8c821cfccc](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9cfc3e18adb0362533e911bf3ce6ec8c821cfccc)**, which says :

> sched: Massage **set_cpus_allowed**()
>
> Thread a u32 flags word through the **set_cpus_allowed** () callchain.
> This will allow adding behavioural tweaks for future users.

I believe *this* is what it means.